# Get Methods and Class-Relationships in UML-Diagrams

Tags: class, get, dependencies, uml, relationship

This question is bugging me over and over again and I cannot find a clear answer to it. For most people this should be trivial to answer, so please, could you please help me using UML correctly?

If I have classes `A`, `B` and `C`. An instance of `B` is a member of `A` and an instance of `C` is a member of `B`. Now `B` offers a method, which returns its member of Class `C` and `A` calls this method in one of his methods and does some actions on it. In UML, is there now a `dependency` between `A` and `C`? Or is it so obvious that the relationship can be ommitted (otherwise the UML diagram could become hard to overlook in no time)? To illustrate the problem, a short sketch of the described situation:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link from A to C is not needed.

The arrows from A to B and B to C show the visibility (or navigation) such that C is visible to B which is itself visible to A, which means that there is an assumed path from A to C and an explicit line does not need to be drawn. Plus, like you say, following that pattern would quickly create an unwieldy diagram.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  There is a dependency between A and C if the type C is known to A.  In this example since an instance of C is being return to A it is necessary.  However, the reason it overly complicated is because the design doesn't follow the Law of Demeter.  A should tell B what to do, which delegates part of that task to C.

Comment: Although I agree with you on the suspected violation of the Law of Demeter, it doesn't change anything with regard to the diagram. If every instance of the type of dependency you mention were to be included in the diagram, it would rapidly consume large amounts of space; either requiring a much larger final output, a reduced font size, or some combination of both. Indirect dependencies do not automatically make the diagram clearer. Maybe if it were a specific sequence diagram involving those classes, sure but for an overview of the domain model, the relationship can be inferred.